# Mapping JSON to DTO

Tags: java, spring

I have a DTO called User whch has the fields  userFirstName,userLastName .Also I have a entity called UserEntity that has the fields id,userFirstName,userLastName.I am not having id field in my JSON payload as that will be autogenerated,so how will the JSON fields map to UserDTO.And i also cannot remove the id field from UserDTO as I am using the same userDTO class to show the list of users where I need to show the id attribute in JSON.How can I use the same USERDTO class for POST and GET request type where in POST request we don't send a id attribute in JSON body and in GET response we need id attribute 
My entity class:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "usr")
    public class User implements Serializable {
    public User() {
     }

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
     @Column(name = "id")
     private Long id;

     @Column(name = "firstName")
     private String userFirstName;

     @Column(name = "lastName")
     private String userLastName;


    // fields with getters / setters for all the fields.
     }
```

My DTO Class
           public class UserDTO {

```
       private Long id;

       private String userFirstName;

       private String userLastName;
      }
```

JSON POST request:

```
  {
  "userFirstName":"testuserFirstName",
  "userLastName":"testuserLastName",

   }
```

This is the response that I want to see when we do a GET request for a list of users :

```
  {
   "id":1,
  "userFirstName":"testuserFirstName",
  "userLastName":"testuserLastName",

   }
```

Code snippet in the controller class method for POST Request

```
          UserDTO requestPayloadData = gson.fromJson(json, UserDTO.class);
```

Comment: GET does not have a body. How do you have request json for your GTE request ?

Comment: It is the JSON  response on Request Type GET

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How can I use the same USERDTO for two different JSON as shown in question for POST and GET ??

Comment: I have updated the question @Jason.Please check now

Answer (score 0):

`You actually need different objects for the task`

I think you mix up the concepts of DTO (Data Transfer Object), which transfers data from your business logic to the front end, and DO (Data Object), which is there for persisting. So you normally never map a DTO to DB columns, this the the job of DOs

---

Another Suggestion, if you want to attain task with same classes.

- Do not populate your entity object USER's ***id*** field

While you copy data from UserDTO to User entity, skip the ***id*** filed

You can even remove the *setter* for ***id*** filed in User entity (if ORM got no issues)

Comment: I am not mapping a DTO to a DB column ,for that I have already created a entity .I am just mapping the JSON to DTO and later using modelmapper mapping the DTO fields to Entity to persist in the database

Comment: @Gitesh You are using same DTO ..to show some list of Users.. as you mentioned in problem statement.

Comment: @Gitesh Using a different DO object while populating the list, form Database

Comment: @Gitesh Added another approach to my answer. Checkout. Hopefully helps! ..else lets discuss more !

Comment: We can discuss in personal chat if you okay with it??

Comment: can you share the link please??@Aditya

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209516/discussion-between-gitesh-and-aditya-rewari).